# python tornado download remote file

Tags: python, download, tornado

I want to download a remote file and give the filename. This method works if the file is on our server. But it doesn't work for remote file and download as somerandomname.pdf

```
<a href="http://file.com/somerandomname.pdf" download="mypdf.pdf">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Now I tried in python handler to download it. It works and download the filename I want. But the problem is that I can only see the downloaded file util the download is complete in the browser. I cannot see the download process in browser. It's just loading the remote file in the backend. Is there a way to fix this?

```
def get(self):
    url = self.get_argument('url')
    filename = self.get_argument('filename')
    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    self.write(f.read())
    self.finish()
```

Comment: As I understand you want to proxy the file? Show your handler

Comment: @kwarunek Yes ur right. I updated my handler. Looks like it's stuck at f.read() to download the file. I also tried AsynHTTPClient.fetch() but they are same. Why browser doesn't show download process, I already send header before read the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Headers are not sent as soon as you call `set_header()`; they are not sent until you call `flush()` or `finish()` (among other things, this is what makes it possible to replace the output with an error page if an exception is raised before the call to `flush()`)
2. Even if you call `flush()`, the entire server is blocked during the call to `urlopen()`. This is a blocking call which must be replaced with an asynchronous version in Tornado (see the [user's guide](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html) for more on this). Tornado provides an asynchronous HTTP client which can be used in place of `urlopen()`:

   ```
   @gen.coroutine
   def get(self):
       url = self.get_argument('url')
       filename = self.get_argument('filename')
       self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
       self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename)

       self.flush()
       response = yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(url)
       self.finish(response.body)
   ```
3. This process loads the entire remote file into memory at once, and doesn't send any of it to the browser until the whole thing has been read from the remote server. If the file is large, you may wish to read it in chunks and send them back to the client as they are read:

   ```
   # inside get() as above, after self.flush():
   def streaming_callback(chunk):
       self.write(chunk)
       self.flush()
   yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(url, streaming_callback=streaming_callback)
   self.finish()
   ```

Comment: Thanks. You save my day! One last thing is that I got timeout error for AsyncHTTPClient().fetch if the file is too large. Can I set timeout in the client?

Comment: Thank you. I figured out timeout issue